# Regex for htaccess that matches multiple words split by hyphen

Tags: regex, .htaccess

For now I'm using this htaccess file in my e-shop script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?category_id=$1&product_id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?category_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It seems SEO friendly and is allowing customer to see nicely printed address bar like:

`mydomain.com/CDPlayers/Sonytr200`

The problem is that I was told to improve engine so instead of `CDPlayers` or `Sonytr200` I should produce `CD-Players` and `Sony-tr-200`. I have to admit that I got that htaccess regex from the web, because I didn't study regex much.

This one isn't working anymore due to fact that it is accepting only one word and now I need something that will allow me to use unlimited number of words split by hyphen so it has to work in following cases:

- `mydomain.com/Word` (stage 1)

or

- `mydomain.com/Word-word-word` (stage 1)

and

- `mydomain.com/Word/Word` (stage 2)

or

- `mydomain.com/Word-word-word/Word-word-word` (stage 2)

Comment: You sure `[\w-]+` isn't mayching words with hyphens?

Comment: it is not unfortunetely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a new recursive rule to remove all hyphens first:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^([^-]*)-+([^-]*-.*)$" $1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule "^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?category_id=$1&product_id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?category_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: if i use your script and hit this url: `mydomain.com/CD-Players` i land on 404 no page `CD-Players`, to be honest i cant even access service hiting `CDPlayers` all together. But even if, goal was to process hyphens not to remove them, as no hyphens means we are back where we were on the first place.

Comment: I am confused now. For a URL of `mydomain.com/Word-word-word/Word-word-word` what should be internal URI?